# Measure on $S^1$

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure

My book gives the following definition of Lebesgue measure on $S^1$:

For each $B\subseteq [0,1]$ in the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, define $\mu(B)=\lambda(B)$. This defines a finite measure $\mu$ on $S^1$ with $\mu(S^1)=1$.

I'm unsure if more needs to be done. These are my thoughts:

Show $\mu$ is well-defined on $[0,1]/\sim\cong S^1$: If $B\in (0,1), [0,1),$ or $(0,1]$, then $B=[B]$ in $S^1$, so $\mu([B])=\mu(B)$. If $B$, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, contains both $0$ and $1$, then $[B]=B\setminus\{1\}$, so $\mu([B])=\mu(B\setminus\{1\})=\lambda(B\setminus\{1\})=\lambda(B)=\mu(B)$ since singletons are zero sets. So in every case, $\mu([B])=\mu(B)$.

Now for a homeomorphism $\phi:[0,1]/\sim\to S^1$, we can define a measure $\upsilon$ on $(S^1,\scr B$$(S^1))$, where $\scr B$$(S^1)$ is borel measure on $S^1$, by $\upsilon(V)=\mu(\phi^{-1}(V))$ for all $V\in\scr B$$(S^1)$.

Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: Defined like this $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are notations for the same measure (this on $[0,1]$ and not on $S^1$).

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Would $\upsilon$ be the measure on $S^1$ the author wants to define?

Comment: $\nu$ indeed defines a measure on $S^1$. A uniform probability measure I would say, since $\nu(S^1)=1$. I am not sure, but from a "Lebesgue measure" I would expect that arcs in $S^1$ are sent to their lengths. That can be achieved by factoring with $2\pi$.